# Accessing Icecast outside AWS Server window instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, icecast

While installing Icecast on AWS window server its working fine with in AWS EC2 instance with port 8000 , But wont get accessed outside even disable firewall setting.I have also change instance security groups to be allowed for all.

Please suggest how can I resolve this and make it accessible outside.

Regards
Kapil